# Passing the current url with routedata to custom error controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass the accessed url to my error controller called `ErrorController` so that I can log what page was being accessed at the time.

In my Global.asax.cs I have a method `Application_Error` looking like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;

    var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
    var currentController = " ";
    var currentAction = " ";

    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }

        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }

    var ex = Server.GetLastError();

    var controller = new ErrorController();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var action = "Index";

    if (ex is HttpException)
    {
        var httpEx = ex as HttpException;

        switch (httpEx.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                action = "NotFound";
                // Pass along some data about accessed page here
                break;

            // others if any

            default:
                action = "Index";
                break;
        }
    }

    httpContext.ClearError();
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() : 500;
    httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = action;

    controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
    ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
}
```

And my `ErrorController` looks like this:

```
public class ErrorController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;
    public ErrorController()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("CustomHandleErrorAttribute.class");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Error/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound(string error)
    {
        _logger.Error(error);
        return View();
    }
}
```

How should I go about populating the error parameter so I can log this to my file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following in my `ErrorController.cs`:

```
if (Request.Url != null)
{
    var path = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    _logger.Error("404: " + path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over complicating it a bit. Just create a shared function that logs the exception and page in your error controller class. This way you can forget about routing all together. You can use the UrlReferrer property on the request to get the page that the error occurred on.

Global.asax (vb.net):

```
Sub Application_Error()

    Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
    Dim page As String = If(Not IsNothing(Request), Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri, Nothing)
    ErrorController.LogError(ex, page)

    Server.ClearError()

End Sub
```